# yocto linux - how to shrink a disk image

Tags: linux, dd, yocto

Noob alert.

I used win32 disk imager to backup a 16Gb Scandisk SD card. I have a batch of Verbatim 16GB SD cards I'm trying to restore the image to. Win32 disk imager complains that they have less sectors.

After reading many posts I thought I could `dd` using `conv=sparse` to create a smaller image sp I...

- Found a 32Gb card
- Restored the image
- As this creates 2 partitions (a fat32 boot and a ext3) I created a 3rd partition using the
  unallocated space Then tried cloning the original 2 partitions to a
  file on the 3rd partition like so...

`dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=512 skip=8192 count=31108096 conv=sparse > /mnt/d/test.img`

Problem is, this file is still huge

```
root@pcu:~# ls -al /mnt/d
total 1355300
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root        4096 Sep  7 17:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root        4096 Sep  7 17:40 ..
drwx------ 2 root root       16384 Sep  7 17:46 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15927345152 Sep  7 18:09 test.img
```

The other problem I have is this is a bespoke (yockto) linux on an embedded chip so I don't believe I can use GParted.

As I'm fully aware I may have missed something with obvious with my lack of experience any help/pointers would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

The end goal is to have an image that I can use with Win32 disk imager to write to SD cards.

Comment: Did you take a look at this ? [https://superuser.com/questions/610819/how-to-resize-img-file-created-with-dd](https://superuser.com/questions/610819/how-to-resize-img-file-created-with-dd)

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the end was clone the second partition, shrank the new partition, shrank the second partition, cloned the third partition back over the second partition. Where "shrank" meant resizing the filesystem with resize2fs and re-creating the partition with fdisk. Then I deleted the third partition. Finally, read the image with Win32 disk imager, remembering to tick the "Read only allocated partitions" box.

I originally tried using the "shrank" method on the second partition without bothering to clone it. This failed. Presumably because it held the OS files.

I wish I had a full blown linux so could have just created a bootable USB and used GParted, etc.